# Multiple Command Buttons

Tags: excel, vba, button, command

I am making a sheet to help with Sudoku and have command buttons from 1 t0 9 that change from the number to blank when pressed.
Code for each button is:-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If CommandButton1.Caption = "1" Then CommandButton1.Caption = "" Else CommandButton1.Caption = "1"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
If CommandButton2.Caption = "2" Then CommandButton2.Caption = "" Else CommandButton2.Caption = "2"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
If CommandButton3.Caption = "3" Then CommandButton3.Caption = "" Else CommandButton3.Caption = "3"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
If CommandButton4.Caption = "4" Then CommandButton4.Caption = "" Else CommandButton4.Caption = "4"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
If CommandButton5.Caption = "5" Then CommandButton5.Caption = "" Else CommandButton5.Caption = "5"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
If CommandButton6.Caption = "6" Then CommandButton6.Caption = "" Else CommandButton6.Caption = "6"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
If CommandButton7.Caption = "7" Then CommandButton7.Caption = "" Else CommandButton7.Caption = "7"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
If CommandButton8.Caption = "8" Then CommandButton8.Caption = "" Else CommandButton8.Caption = "8"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
If CommandButton9.Caption = "9" Then CommandButton9.Caption = "" Else CommandButton9.Caption = "9"
End Sub
```

I want to copy and past these nine buttons and have the code retained in the command button but have the button number change in the code but keep the rest of the code the same. Is that possible.

```
Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()
If CommandButton1.Caption = "1" Then CommandButton1.Caption = "" Else CommandButton1.Caption = "1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [class resp. control array](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/) (another example [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm)) for that but possibly the easiest way for you is just to use the following Sub

```
Sub chCaption(newCaption As String, ctrl As MSForms.Control)
    With ctrl
        If .Caption = newCaption Then
            .Caption = ""
        Else
            .Caption = newCaption
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

like that

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    chCaption "1", Me.CommandButton1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    chCaption "2", Me.CommandButton2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below will do what you want. Install it as it is in the code sheet in which you have the command buttons or make it public and install it in a standard code module, depending upon whether you need to call it only from one sheet or several.

```
Private Sub ResetButton(ByVal Id As Integer)
    ' 028

    Dim BtnVal As Integer

    BtnVal = Id Mod 9
    If BtnVal = 0 Then BtnVal = 9

    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton" & Id).Object
        .Caption = IIf(Len(.Caption), "", BtnVal)
    End With
End Sub
```

This code extracts a Soduko number from the CommandButton number by using the MOD function. CommandButtons1 to 9 would hold the numbers 1 to 9 as would 10 to 18, 19 to 27 etc. For each button you need a procedure like the one below to be present in the worksheet's code module.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 028
    ResetButton 1
End Sub
```

The parameter in each copy of this is different, being identical to the number of the CommandButton to which it responds.

While this should do what you requested I doubt that it's the best way to go about the task. Instead of the CommandButton I recommend a shape, like a Rectangle which is both easier to program and to paint. Presuming you have 9 rectangles named `Rectangle 1` thru 9, you would assign the same code to all of them, not requiring any customization. This code.

```
Sub ResetSodukoButton()
    ' 028

    Dim Caller As String
    Dim BtnVal  As Integer

    Caller = Application.Caller
    BtnVal = Split(Caller)(1) Mod 9
    If BtnVal = 0 Then BtnVal = 9

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Caller).TextFrame.Characters
        .Text = IIf(Len(.Text), "", BtnVal)
    End With
End Sub
```

The code will identify the shape that was clicked, read its name, produce a Sudoku number from it using the same interpretation by the MOD function and set the number accordingly. You save the hassle of having all the `CommandButtonX_Click` procedures.

install the sub `ResetSodukoButton` in a standard code module.